# Stanford NER Error: Loading distsim lexicon Failed

Tags: java, ide, stanford-nlp

In my project. I need to use NER annotation so I used NERDemo.java
It works fine when I create a new project and have only this code, but when I add it to my project I keep getting errors. I have edited the path in my code to the specific location of the classifiers.

I added the Jar files:

[image]

This is the code:

```
String serializedClassifier = "/Users/ha/stanford-ner-2014-10-26/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
    String serializedClassifier2 = "/Users/ha/stanford-ner-2014-10-26/classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";

    if (args.length > 0) {
      serializedClassifier = args[0];
    }

    NERClassifierCombiner classifier = new NERClassifierCombiner(false, false, serializedClassifier, serializedClassifier2);

    String fileContents = IOUtils.slurpFile("/Users/ha/NetBeansProjects/StanfordPOSCode/src/stanfordposcode/input.txt");
    List<List<CoreLabel>> out = classifier.classify(fileContents);

    int i = 0;
    for (List<CoreLabel> lcl : out) {
      i++;
      int j = 0;
      for (CoreLabel cl : lcl) {
        j++;
        System.out.printf("%d:%d: %s%n", i, j,
                cl.toShorterString("Text", "CharacterOffsetBegin", "CharacterOffsetEnd", "NamedEntityTag"));
      }
    }
```

But I got this error:

```
run:
Loading classifier from /Users/ha/stanford-ner-2014-10-26/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... Loading distsim lexicon from /u/nlp/data/pos_tags_are_useless/egw4-reut.512.clusters ... java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /u/nlp/data/pos_tags_are_useless/egw4-reut.512.clusters (No such file or directory)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory$ReaderIterator.setNextObject(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:225)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory$ReaderIterator.<init>(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:161)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory.iterator(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:98)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank$OBIterator.<init>(ObjectBank.java:404)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank.iterator(ObjectBank.java:242)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERFeatureFactory.initLexicon(NERFeatureFactory.java:471)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERFeatureFactory.init(NERFeatureFactory.java:379)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.reinit(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:171)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.loadClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2630)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1620)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1736)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1679)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1662)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.getClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2851)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifierFromPath(ClassifierCombiner.java:189)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifiers(ClassifierCombiner.java:173)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.<init>(ClassifierCombiner.java:125)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.<init>(NERClassifierCombiner.java:52)
    at stanfordposcode.MultipleNERs.main(MultipleNERs.java:24)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /u/nlp/data/pos_tags_are_useless/egw4-reut.512.clusters (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.EncodingFileReader.<init>(EncodingFileReader.java:78)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory$ReaderIterator.setNextObject(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:192)
    ... 18 more
Loading classifier from /Users/ha/stanford-ner-2014-10-26/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifierFromPath(ClassifierCombiner.java:199)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifiers(ClassifierCombiner.java:173)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.<init>(ClassifierCombiner.java:125)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.<init>(NERClassifierCombiner.java:52)
    at stanfordposcode.MultipleNERs.main(MultipleNERs.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to edu.stanford.nlp.classify.LinearClassifier
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ner.CMMClassifier.loadClassifier(CMMClassifier.java:1070)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1620)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1736)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1679)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1662)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ner.CMMClassifier.getClassifier(CMMClassifier.java:1116)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifierFromPath(ClassifierCombiner.java:195)
    ... 4 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing and matching the code from version 3.4 and the models from version 3.5.  I suggest upgrading everything to the latest version.