# Stanford CoreNLP - the egw4-reut.512.clusters cannot be found

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am using the CoreNLP package to do some annotation on user comments and since I have upgraded to the 3.5.0 version I seem to repeatedly run into the same error:

> Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ...
>
> Loading distsim lexicon from /u/nlp/data/pos_tags_are_useless/egw4-reut.512.clusters ...
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \u\nlp\data\pos_tags_are_useless\egw4-reut.512.clusters (The system cannot find the path specified) 
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory$ReaderIterator.setNextObject(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:225) (cue fifty lines of error)

A few searches here got me these similar questions:

[Stanford NER Error: Loading distsim lexicon Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482591/stanford-ner-error-loading-distsim-lexicon-failed) and [Stanford NER tagger generates 'file not found' exception with provided models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569466/stanford-ner-tagger-generates-file-not-found-exception-with-provided-models) which did not solve my issue: I am exclusively using code and models from the 3.5.0 (via Maven Central). I tried modifying the props file from the NER model and pointing towards another .clusters file in a user directory with no success (exact same error).

The code I use to instantiate the CoreNLP object is pretty standard too, but here it is:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
    stan = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

Now I am thinking that there is something obvious that I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A more complete stacktrace (if that can help) is as follows:

```
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... Loading distsim lexicon from /u/nlp/data/pos_tags_are_useless/egw4-reut.512.clusters ... java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \u\nlp\data\pos_tags_are_useless\egw4-reut.512.clusters (The system cannot find the path specified)
at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory$ReaderIterator.setNextObject(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:225)
at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory$ReaderIterator.<init>(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:161)
at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory.iterator(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:98)
at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank$OBIterator.<init>(ObjectBank.java:404)
at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank.iterator(ObjectBank.java:242)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERFeatureFactory.initLexicon(NERFeatureFactory.java:471)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERFeatureFactory.init(NERFeatureFactory.java:379)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.reinit(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:171)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.loadClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2630)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1620)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1675)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1662)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.getClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2851)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifierFromPath(ClassifierCombiner.java:189)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifiers(ClassifierCombiner.java:173)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.<init>(ClassifierCombiner.java:113)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.<init>(NERClassifierCombiner.java:64)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$6.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:617)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:85)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:267)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:129)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:125)
at rgu.jclos.quilt.utilities.nlp.DependenciesTagger.<init>(DependenciesTagger.java:99)
at rgu.jclos.quilt.eca.approaches.ApproachC_USS.main(ApproachC_USS.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \u\nlp\data\pos_tags_are_useless\egw4-reut.512.clusters (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.EncodingFileReader.<init>(EncodingFileReader.java:78)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory$ReaderIterator.setNextObject(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:192)
    ... 23 more
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$6.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:621)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:85)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:267)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:129)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:125)
    at rgu.jclos.quilt.utilities.nlp.DependenciesTagger.<init>(DependenciesTagger.java:99)
    at rgu.jclos.quilt.eca.approaches.ApproachC_USS.main(ApproachC_USS.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifierFromPath(ClassifierCombiner.java:199)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifiers(ClassifierCombiner.java:173)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.<init>(ClassifierCombiner.java:113)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.<init>(NERClassifierCombiner.java:64)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$6.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:617)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to edu.stanford.nlp.classify.LinearClassifier
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ner.CMMClassifier.loadClassifier(CMMClassifier.java:1070)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1620)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1675)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1662)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ner.CMMClassifier.getClassifier(CMMClassifier.java:1116)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifierFromPath(ClassifierCombiner.java:195)
... 10 more
```

Comment: Could you include the full output of your run, or of a minimal example that replicates the problem? This lexicon should already have been loaded with the model (the error is it trying to re-load it from our filesystem), which leads me to believe that either the models are corrupt, or something went wrong earlier. Another thing to check is to make sure your model version is the same as your CoreNLP version.

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue thanks to your comment. The Stanford library was used in a utility class for processing its output. The models and the code are both 3.5.0 in the project which uses them, but it turns out the issue was with Maven which was mixing up transitive dependencies and importing files from 3.4 behind my back in the project which uses that utility class, causing the confusion and subsequent bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was caused by Maven.

My code was located in a utility library which was wrapping over the Stanford CoreNLP to provide additional processing, and was working perfectly well by itself. However when adding this project as a dependency to my master project, Maven defaulted to importing version 3.4 of the Stanford CoreNLP library models to the master project, which caused the bug described above.